# Запись файла в директорию

Tags: android, java, файлы

```
 File dir = android.os.Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory();
             file =  new File(dir + File.separator + "Music1.mp3");
             if (!file.exists()) {
                 file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                 file.createNewFile(); 
                }

             fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
             inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Задача моя - загрузить файл в директорию загрузок, но на `file.createNewFile()` выдает исключение. Может в пути какая-то ошибка?

Comment: ошибку покажи

Comment: System.err(275): java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

добавь в манифест

**UPD**

что бы писать в директорию приложение надо юзать `this.getFilesDir()` , `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`- это всего лишь текстовая константа пути -  "/sdcard", потому файл пишется на карту...

насчет getDownloadCacheDirectory - точно не скажу, возможно папка Cache как-то защине отдельно...

Comment: добавлял я его

Comment: пиши сюда Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Сработало)Можете пояснить почему так было?Да и файл записываеться в память телефона или на карту?Если на карту ,то как можно записать на память телефона?

Answer (score 0):

Надо:

```
dir + File.pathSeparator + "Music1.mp3"
```

Вообще то такие элементарные ошибки отлавливаются или отладчиком или логгером...

Comment: да ну...... pathSeparator = :, а separator = /, так что у него правильно

Comment: `File.pathSeparator` это разделитель путей при перечислении. Может быть `;` или `:` в зависимости от системы.